# Maria DB backup generates zero KB file with no errors

Tags: mariadb, backup

[image: Maria DB backup file remains zero KB, though no errors are seen on the screen.]
The backup command line runs for ever and neither generates the data in the backup file nor throughs any error.

THis was working fine earlier, it stopped suddenly, no changes have been done to the DB or DB config.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `mysql` command, not the `mysqldump` command.